# TypeScript complains either about 'implicit any' or 'possibly undefined' even if it is not possible

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to decrease a property in an object by 1 if it exists and is greater than 0 but TypeScript won't compile this code whatever I try.

```
interface IStatus {
  [key: string]: number | undefined; // <= I don't want undefined here but it complains since the params are optional
  burning?: number;
  firing?: number;
}

class Thing {
  public status: IStatus = {};
  private processStatus() {
    for (const key in this.status) {
      if (
        this.status.hasOwnProperty(key) &&
        this !== undefined &&
        this.status !== undefined &&
        this.status[key] !== undefined && // <= Complains about implicit any without the index signature
        this.status[key] > 0 // <= Complains about possibly undefined with the index signature
      ) {
        this.status[key]--;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Typescript all properties of a type with an index signature have to adhere to that signature, which is why it requires you to include `undefined` as part of the index value. This is a mechanism to make sure that the type of a property is consistent regardless of if you access it using bracket notation (`status["burning"]`) or with dot notation (`status.burning`).

But you can get around this by using an intersection type to combine the index signature and your other properties:

```
type IStatus = {
  [key: string]: number; // <= No undefined here anymore
} & {
  burning?: number;
  firing?: number;
}
```

Using that, `this.status[key]` is inferred to have type `number`, but `this.status.burning` is inferred to have type `number | undefined`.

As noted earlier, you'll want to be careful since now you can change the inferred type of the `burning` property by how you access it. If you use `this.status["burning"]`, the type is inferred as just `number`.

Answer (score 2):

`Object is possibly 'undefined'` error can be eliminated by using [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions) (exclamation sign):

```
  if (
    ...
    this.status[key]! > 0
  ) {
    this.status[key]!--;
  }
```

If it's possible to address the problem by proper typing (as another answer suggests), that's the preferable way.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler does not "remember" the result of `this.status[key] !== undefined` check, it's a known [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15582) / [limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530). The workaround is to use intermediate variable:

```
interface IStatus {
  [key: string]: number | undefined; // <= I don't want undefined here but it complains since the params are optional
  burning?: number;
  firing?: number;
}

class Thing {
  public status: IStatus = {};
  private processStatus() {
      for (const key in this.status) {
          const value = this.status[key];  
          if (value !== undefined && value > 0) {
              this.status[key] = value - 1;
          }
      }
  }
}
```